# JavaScript: iterating over document.evaluate() XPathResult returns null

Tags: javascript, xpath, document.evaluate

I am trying to get all  objects but it doesn't work.

```
var tmp = document.evaluate("//tr", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
```

`tmp.iterateNext` returns me null;

Answer (score 2):

If you are working in IE, then you should know that `document.evaluate` does not exist there (see [this similar question](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/528706-ie-equivalent-firefox-document-evaluate) and [the last couple of paragraphs here](http://js-xpath.sourceforge.net/)).

Why not just `document.getElementsByTagName("tr");`?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, using an existing JS libraries such as JQuery is usually more reliable in cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
```

It also will not work, because IE some versions doesn't support this method for elements, which has not such attribute like 'name'.